# can i capture actual address bar url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Help me please. How could I get the url from the address bar. Im using c# for this.  for example: if I type www.google.com in my address bar, then i would get "www.google.com" caption.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to handle incoming requests to your web server.

Depending on your setup, you should be able to access the url the user used to reach you with `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

here is a cheat sheet I use for myself to get an overview of the Uri object:
[image]